Why do shocks travel further down the wing as the Mach number increases?
Inspired by this question, why do shocks move further back on a wing as the Mach number increases?
Normal shocks on the surfaces of wings form when the air molecules of the pressure recovery area on the wing don’t have time to react to the incoming air. Not having time to react causes a rapid compression of the air, making a shockwave.
Now if the air on the wing was traveling faster, when it got to the pressure recovery, it would just collapse into a stronger shock but in the same position, right? Why does it not do that and instead move further back in the wing?

Some pictures to see what I’m taking about :

This is when the shock is half down the wing. (Ignore the separation part of the photo)


Then at a higher speed, the shocks for some reason move backwards instead of just staying where they were and getting stronger. Why is that?

@sophit good point. Separation will still cause drag, but not wave drag in this case.

The boundary layer separation aft of the shock wave does not cause wave drag as suggested in the first picture. Wave drag is an intrinsic drag generated at supersonic speeds and has nothing to do with boundary layer. As already suggested by @RobMcDonald beware of random pictures from the internet. Btw, what's the source of that picture?

@sophit The latest response ever, but the source is here

Again...

Why would it stay in the same place?  Is there some physical object to keep it there?  Something like a ridge or a bump or a throat of a nozzle?
On a smooth surface, the location a shock 'chooses' is determined by a balance of effects.  One of those is the upstream Mach number -- as the airfoil goes faster, the supersonic region around the airfoil gets larger and the Mach number in it gets larger.  Another is the back pressure.
Without worrying about the details, when we're faced with a balance of factors like this, there is no reason to think they will be the same as you vary the important conditions.  In fact, it makes a lot more sense for them to be different.
Edit
Adding an image to illustrate the behavior the OP was asking about



I see, but I assumed the back pressure stays the same as the Mach number increases. Is this true? If so, it seems like it’d collapse in the same place?

It would make sense if the back pressure decreased as you speed up, then the shock would travel backwards. Not sure why it would decrease or change though.

It doesn't actually matter if the back pressure stays the same or not.  When the Mach number is higher, the normal shock will be stronger.  A stronger shock means a larger pressure jump at the shock.  Check out the normal shock tables.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_shock_tables

I came back to this answer because I am a little confused. Imagine you’re going Mach 0.82 like in the picture at the bottom of your answer. When the air accelerates to supersonic, it is forced to decelerate through a normal shock when it arrives at the pressure recovery area. When you increase speed, why wouldn’t it just force this normal shock to be stronger and stay in the same spot?

@Wyatt  Unfortunately, the picture I originally posted does not show the whole picture.  The experimental image was too zoomed in.  Check out the illustration I've now added.  Notice that when you get to supersonic flow, a bow shock forms before the rounded airfoil leading edge.  The bow shock is a normal shock (strong shock solution, subsonic flow downstream) that then bends around and becomes an oblique shock away from the body.  This illustration gives a good indication of the regions of subsonic and supersonic flow.

I see. So if you’re subsonic, increasing speed from Mach .70 -> .90 the shockwave will travel down the wing like in the new picture you added. In this speed range there is no bow shock. In this case, why wouldn’t the shock just increase strength but stay in the same spot relative to the wing?  Sorry if I’m not picking up on something you’ve already answered.

Why would it stay the same strength?  The upstream conditions are changing.

I do think it would change strength. (Perhaps I worded my comment poorly), but I do not see why it would change position on the wing. If the supersonic air is going to collapse into a normal shock, why would it collapse in a different position based on speed? Maybe I should ask a separate question if this is too much to answer in a comments section.

Think of it this way.  The position of the shock is a delicate equilibrium position.  It is like balancing on top of a ball.  Change anything and you will find a different equilibrium position.  The incoming flow (Mach, Pressure) goes through a shock to a higher pressure.  That pressure must match the downstream flow.  The shock will move to find the point where this is true.

I see. So could one way to think of it be that when the lift distribution of the airfoil changes, that in turn changes the shock position? This question has a good picture of what I mean. Basically when those arrows are in different proportions relative to the others, that will change the shock position. Is that correct?

You can't boil most things in fluid dynamics down to a simple cause and effect -- step 1, step 2, step3.  Typically, you must simultaneously solve for 1,2,3 as a coupled problem.  Most people would say the shock causes the pressure distribution around the airfoil, however, the position of the shock does depend on the acceleration (pressure and Mach number) ahead of it.

I see. I think I understand this more now. Definitely agree that a lot of things in fluid mechanics are not simple cause and effect relationships. Thanks.
